# How do I prevent multiple IE windows when using VBA on MS Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, url

I added a button to my Access form to generate an image from a confidential web application. The URL contains a drop-down field for year, a text box for SFN (six-digit  unique ID when combined with year), and a button to search for the image.  Using values from the record currently listed in the form, the code below successfully populates the year drop-down field and seemingly correctly populates the SFN field; a six digit string appears in the box.  However, the code opens up a new window each time the button is pressed. I'd like for the code to either close the old window first or populate the new values in the window that is already open.

VBA is not my area of expertise.  I appreciate any input.

```
Private Sub IMAGED_Click()

    Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    browser.navigate ("https://www.confidentialWebApp.com")
    browser.StatusBar = False
    browser.Toolbar = False
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.Resizable = False
    browser.AddressBar = True

    Dim yearVal As String
    Dim SFNVal As String
    yearVal = Mid(B_SFN, 4, 4)
    SFNVal = Mid(B_SFN, 8, 6)

    browser.Document.getElementById("YearListBox").Value = yearVal
    browser.Document.getElementById("SFN_TextBox").Value = SFNVal
    browser.Document.getElementById("ImageDisplayButton").Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle by declaring browser as a Public object variable then try to Quit it in procedure and handle error if it is not open. Sometimes helps for code to Wait until browser loaded before trying to access elements although in your case that doesn't seem necessary.

```
Public browser As InternetExplorer
________________________________________

Sub IMAGED_Click()
On Error Resume Next
browser.Quit
Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With browser
    .Navigate ("https://www.confidentialWebApp.com")
    .StatusBar = False
    .Toolbar = False
    .Visible = True
    .Resizable = False
    .AddressBar = True
    Do
        'Wait till the Browser is loaded
    Loop Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    .Document.getElementById("YearListBox").Value = Mid(B_SFN, 4, 4)
    .Document.getElementById("SFN_TextBox").Value = Mid(B_SFN, 8, 6)
    .Document.getElementById("ImageDisplayButton").Click
End With
End Sub
```

Another version of wait:

```
While .Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
```

Or instead of Quit and handling error, test if browser exists.

```
If browser Is Nothing Then
'code to set browser
End If
```

Just be aware that global/public variables lose value if code is terminated mid-run, say as happens during run-time error.

Need some way to set browser to Nothing when work session is completed. If all code is behind form, just closing form should clear object variable. If code is in a general module, will need to explicitly clear variable and maybe even quit IE, perhaps in form Close event:

```
If Not browser Is Nothing Then
    browser.Quit
    Set browser = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I edited my text to include just one question.  I tried your code and it opens the URL in IE but the fields are no longer populated and it seems to lockup Access.  I can't navigate between the form and the VBA code and I can't move to the next record.

Comment: Code works for me in a simple test just to open IE to a web page like `"http://www.allenbrowne.com/tips.html"`. Suggest you test that before trying with your page. Since I cannot work with your page, cannot advise correction.

Comment: I have only ever had to code this once. My code to fill in elements is different. `oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctLoginName").Value = "alaskadot"`